# Android studio is not suggesting the attributes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, attributes

I was working on android studio from the past few days but today I was facing the problem that I have to write complete attributes. android studio is not showing any suggestion for the attributes in activity_main.xml.for details please see the image that only a few suggestions are visible and I have already reinstalled the complete android studio even after deleting all files and folders from C drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in android studio:
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart-> Then  Click  Invalidate and Restart.

Or this:
File ->Power Save Mode and disable it.

Comment: thanks but I had already done this and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

First close android studio
Go to path/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/  delete caches folder 
then start Android Studio

this is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done all the tricks but nothing worked and in the end, I had completely deleted my android studio uninstalled it manually removed each and every directory and this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that would suggest to you. Just check for update and update your Android Studio. Then this problem will be solved. In this way, you don't need to reinstall the studio and your custom settings. However updating studio might cause some unexpected errors for you.